# How to pass std::thread as thread id in PostThreadMessage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

How could I pass the id of a `std::thread` thread as the id into `PostThreadMessage`?

Like suppose, I have a thread:

```
// Worker Thread

auto thread_func = [](){
    while(true) {
        MSG msg;
        if(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            // Do appropriate stuff depending on the message
        }
    }
};

std::thread thread_not_main = std::thread(thread_func);
```

And then I want to send a message from my main thread to the above thread so that I can handle the message in a *non-expensive* way. So as to not interrupt the main thread.

Like:

```
 // Main Thread

 while(true) {
     MSG msg;
     while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
          TranslateMessage(&msg);
          if(msg.message == WM_PAINT) {
              PostThreadMessage(); // How do I pass the thread id into the function?
          } else {
               DispatchMessage(&msg);
          }
     }
}
```

The summary of the problem is that
[`PostThreadMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagew) requires a ***thread-id*** to be passed in as a parameter,
now `std::thread::get_id` doesn't provide it in a *"`DWORD` convertible format"*. So then I can't pass the thread's id as a parameter.

My question is: How would I pass the thread id as a parameter to `PostThreadMessage`?

Comment: I don't do Win32 anymore but looks like you are running the main message loop in a thread. I don't think it's safe to do so. AFAIK it has to run in the main thread

Comment: Oh ok, i will change that, but still how would I pass the thread id?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [`std::thread::native_handle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle).

Comment: I don't think it is sending a message to the *"worker thread"*. Or no message that `GetMessage` is able to catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the underlying, "Windows-style" thread handle for a `std::thread` object by calling its [`native_handle()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle). From that, you can retrieve the thread's ID by calling the [`GetThreadId` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadid), and passing that native handle as its argument.

Here's a short code snippet that may be what you'd want in the case you've outlined:

```cpp
    auto tHandle = thread_not_main.native_handle(); // Gets a "HANDLE"
    auto tID = GetThreadId(tHandle);                // Gets a DWORD ID
    if (msg.message == WM_PAINT) {
        PostThreadMessage(tID, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    //...
```

Comment: Ok so I seems I may have another problem. How do I check what message(like `WM_PAINT` or `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`) I have received in `if` statement in the main thread? Because It doesn't seem to catch any messages

Comment: That's another question, and *could* be posted as such. :)

Comment: So should I ask a new question or ... ?

Comment: @AmritSanjeev That's up to you. Hopefully, the *specific* issue in this question has been resolved by my answer.

Comment: @AmritSanjeev Yes, that would need to be posted as a separate question. How to get a `std::thread`'s ID, and how to identify a message, are two completely different questions. But you already know how to do the latter (look at the `msg.message` field).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yet I am still not able to catch it.

Comment: I have posted the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546046/how-to-get-what-message-has-been-received-after-calling-translatemessage-on-the

Comment: Note that the C++ standard does not impose **any** requirements on the return type or value of `native_handle()`; in fact, it is not even required to exist. It's behavior is **entirely** implementation defined. So consult your compiler documentation.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed. But, for any compiler that *claims* to support use of the WinAPI, it would be somewhat unhelpful if it didn't provide the relevant windows `HANDLE` object for the return value of `.native_handle()`.

Comment: @AdrianMole -- unfortunately, the Windows API is not that monolithic. When I implemented threading for Dinkumware's standard library there were things on some Windows platforms (i.e., WINCE) that you couldn't do with just a `HANDLE`, so our internal representation had both a `HANDLE` and a thread id (I don't remember the specific data type).

Comment: Your question makes sense but your program does not. You need to handle WM_PAINT in the same thread which receives the message. You can't offload it to a different thread.

Comment: @AdrianMole all implementations of `native_handle()` on Windows are not guaranteed to return a Win32 `HANDLE`. It depends on the implementation. MSVC's implementation does, but other implementations might not.

Answer (score 0):

`std::thread` does not expose the Win32 Thread ID that `PostThreadMessage()` wants.

The best way to handle this issue is to call `GetCurrentThreadId()` inside of your thread function itself, saving the result to a variable that you can then use with `PostThreadMessage()` when needed.

For example:

```
struct threadInfo
{
    DWORD id;
    std::condition_variable hasId;
};

auto thread_func = [](threadInfo &info){
    info.id = GetCurrentThreadId();
    info.hasId.notify_one();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        // Do appropriate stuff depending on the message
    }
};

...

threadInfo info;
std::thread thread_not_main(thread_func, std::ref(info));
info.hasId.wait();
...
PostThreadMessage(info.id, ...);
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution:

You can use the `native_handle()` member function to get the underlying platform-specific handle of the thread, and then pass that to `PostThreadMessage()`:

```
std::thread thread_not_main = std::thread(thread_func);

...

PostThreadMessage(thread_not_main.native_handle(), WM_PAINT, 0, 0);
```

Comment: In Microsoft's implementation of `std::thread`, at least, [`native_handle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-class?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019#native_handle) returns the thread `HANDLE`, not the thread ID: "*`native_handle_type native_handle();` ... `native_handle_type` is defined as a Win32 `HANDLE` that's cast as `void *`.*" But `PostThreadMessage()` needs a thread ID instead of a handle.